# linking info of pairs of respondents (couples) in SPSS

Tags: statistics, analysis, data-analysis, spss

I am preparing for analyses of the determinants of partner choice in SPSS, but basically I can't get off the ground because I don't know how to create new variables based on the information of each respondent's spouse (i.e. education, wages, social background, ethnicity etc.).

Each respondent is currently identified by an ID#, and exist two places in the matrix: as unit/respondent and as a spouse (either wife or husband), instantiated in a different column. What I need is to use info from each row of variables pertaining to an individual as respondent - to create new variables in the row of each person's spouse.

If it helps, I also have a separate file with all couples linked row-wise, as variables of the same unit - evidently with the same ID# as in my "variables-file" (yesterday, however, I merged these files - hopefully correctly...).

Comment: Could you provide a brief view of what your data looks like?  I use SPSS everyday and may be able to help, I am just having a hard time visualizing your data and what you need to do.

Comment: this problem was solved some time ago - but thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a variables called `age`, `weight`, `id` and `spouse_id` in a file called `main.sav`

1. Make a copy of `main.sav` and call it `spouse.sav`
2. Relabel all the content variables in `spouse.sav`: i.e., make `age` `spouse_age` and `weigh` `spouse_weight`
3. Remove the variable `id` from `spouse.sav`
4. Open `main.sav` and merge in `spouse.sav` on the common ID `spouse_id`. I.e., `data - merge files - add variables`